# Python Eve: Add _id value in auth_field with event hook

Tags: python, eve

I have a registration endpoint where no authentication is required for POST requests, therefore also no AUTH_FIELD is added to the mongodb collection when an account is created.

As I need the user-restricted resource access also for this endpoint, I'm trying to add the field with a post event hook:

AUTH_FIELD = 'user_id'

```
def adduserid(request, payload):
  data = json.loads(payload.get_data().decode('utf-8'))
  setid = data['_id']
  app.data.driver.db['accounts'].update({"username" : username},{"$set": {"user_id": setid}})

app.on_post_POST_accounts += adduserid
```

I get a KeyError as result:

```
File "run.py", line 30, in adduserid
setid = data['_id']
KeyError: '_id'
```

I have the feeling that I'm parsing this payload object in a wrong way, but I don't know what's wrong.
Maybe there is an easier way to do it at all?

Comment: How is the `public_methods` and `public_item_methods` settings for this resource?

Comment: `public_methods = ['POST']` for this resource to allow users to create their accounts without account data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `_id` field is not part of the payload, but you will have access to it if you use an `on_inserted_<resource_name>` database hook, since eve adds `_id` before making the database insert. Documentation here (http://python-eve.org/features.html#database-event-hooks)

Comment: Thanks, with the on_inserted_accounts hook it works! `def adduserid(documents):
    for document in documents:
        username = document['username']
        table = app.data.driver.db['accounts']
        user = table.find_one({'username': username})
        setid = user['_id']
        table.update({"username" : username},{"$set": {"user_id": setid}})`